# Apple Music doesn't recognize my music library

Tags: music

I recently got a new Mac with Monterey. I migrated my old music lib for iTunes from Mojave.

After pointing "Music Media folder location" to my music lib, it didn't read anything.

Do I have to re-drag them all? I noticed both versions (Music and iTunes) follow same folder structure.

Comment: How exactly  did you migrate the users and music from the old to the new computer? The important files here are `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Library.*`

Comment: @mmmm thanks, I only migrate my media folder, and ignored those indexing or metadata whatever things completely.

Comment: Ah well form Music/iTunes migrate the metadata and the app can be told to reorganise/reimport the media. If you really do not care about the metadata then just File->Import

Comment: @mmmm that's cool.